# login selenium tests for django all auth fails

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth==0.32.0 for user authentication and it works when I do it manually (signup/login/logout/etc.).

My models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

My views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def CategoryView(request):
    context = {
        'data': 'data',
    }
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html',context)
```

Now, I am trying to write tests with Selenium StaticLiveServerTestCase for it:

```
def test_login(self):
        uname = "Herbert"
        pw = "klaus1234"
        User.objects.create(username=uname,password=pw)
        login_page = "/accounts/login"
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, login_page))
        self.selenium.maximize_window()
        self.selenium.find_element_by_id("id_login").send_keys(uname)
        self.selenium.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys(pw)
        self.selenium.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")[0].click()
```

When I run it, it looks like I the correct data gets posted into the input fields, exactly how it does when I do it manually. But what I am getting is this:

"The username and/or password you specified are not correct."

And the page doesn't redirect to the page specified in `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`

To validate that the data I am posting is correct I added these lines which don't throw an error:

```
self.assertEqual(1,len(Profile.objects.all()))
self.assertEqual(uname,Profile.objects.all()[0].user.username)
self.assertEqual(pw,Profile.objects.all()[0].user.password)
self.assertEqual(uname,User.objects.all()[0].username)
self.assertEqual(pw,User.objects.all()[0].password)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Add lots of log statements to your login view, so you can see all the decisions it made and all the values it received.  This should point you in the right direction. (Also, does your `User` model really store plaintext passwords?)

Comment: That's another thing, when I check in the `./manage.py shell` all the passwords are in hash, but when I print them out during the tests, they somehow appear in plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite Old post, But I think the problem here is with how user creation is done.

Currently you are using following way to create user.

`User.objects.create(username=uname,password=pw)`

For any other object this would have been a great choice, but User should be created as follow:

`User.objects.create_user(username=uname,password=pw)`

This is the very reason why you are seeing that password un-encrypted(plain-text).

Comment: this worked, here (I believe) is the link to the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#manager-methods